# Rails constants for page content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, constants

Currently building a Rails 3 app and I've notice there are a lot of words and phrases that I use in many different views multiple times. Rather than hard-coding them in the views each time, I thought it might be a good idea to have the content stored in a CONSTANTS hash. Would it make sense to make a constants.rb file in config/initializers and then have a hash in it called CONSTANTS, then whenever I need to content for a view, I'd just call the CONSTANTS hash with a respective key? Is this a good way of going about it, or should I do something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like Rails locale files might be what you want. You would define your strings in `config/locales/en.yml` (for English) file. You define your strings in a yaml file, then use them via `t (:my_string)` in your views. It makes it easier to maintain, or to extend to another language.

Take a look at [Rails i18n Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html), it explains things in detail.